# android elevation is not working when I add style attribute into two buttons

Tags: android

I have to build like this layout

[image]

I have added the style to button1 and added an elevation successfully, but when I try to add the same style to the button2, then I will lose the elevation effect for both buttons, I have tried to add android:clipToPadding="false" to the parent layout, but also this one did not work.

Here it is the code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:text="@string/messages_popup_block_user_block"
        android:textColor="@color/color_red_a400"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:text="@string/search_contacts_invite"
        android:textColor="#0797A4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

anyone can help me what is the problem?
and why this is happened?
and what is the best practice to build such like this layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that a parent's bounds cutoff the shadow of its children for some reason

So I have replaced the buttons with a cardViews, and each cardview had a background style.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/button_stranger_block"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardElevation="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha="0.9"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:text="@string/messages_popup_chat_user_block"
                android:textColor="@color/color_red_900"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this was fixed the problem.